# springboot logging config invalid

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j

I would like to have all the internal Springboot log messages directed to log4j so that the messages follow my log4j properties,but it is invalid.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

> ***logging.config=file:/data/log/report-log4j.properties***

start up springboot,it outputs

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly

***but,report-log4j.properties in classpath,it is success。***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it . because spring-boot version1.4 not support log4j

Answer (score 0):

It's not invalid, you just forgot to add a log4j.properties file in your resource directory.

It normally has the following content:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: by logging.config=file:/data/log/report-log4j.properties